# \section{} won't work as I am getting an underfull hbox warning

Tags: sectioning

I am using overleaf and I am pretty new to it and do not know much about Latex as a language.

However, the issue I am having is that I am trying to write "\section{Introduction}" into the source code. When viewed in the compiler the section introduction is not numbered nor emboldened, the next use of "\section{}" however works fine and as intended but the first does not.

When I hover over the yellow exclamation point is says "under-full badness value 10000".

I am using a template from my University (has various imports and code which ensures sections are emboldened) which I have used once before and this never happened. In a nutshell, why won't the command \subsection{} work and how can I fix it??

Comment: An underfull box has nothing to do with bold.

Comment: Is there any way we can take a look at your template? or at-least the relevant sections to see what is causing the underfull error

Comment: Are you have a problem with `\section` or `\subsection` or both?

Comment: You need to be much more exact with your description, preferably including a small complete test.  Your last sentence asks why `\subsection{}` does not work. that is the first time you mentioned `\subsection` do you mean `\subsection{}` with empty argument, or did you mean `\section{}` with empty argument or did you mean any use of `\subsection` ?  The underfull hbox warning means white space is being over-stretched while line breaking and is not related to font choice.  Whether subsections are bold or numbered depends on the declarations in the class file about which you have given no clues.